# Why are the magnifying powers of microscopes & telescopes defined in terms of ratio of angles & not in terms of ratio of sizes of objects & images?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, telescopes

The magnifying power of microscopes and telescopes is defined as follows:

$$m=\frac{\color{red}{\text{Angle}} \text{ subtended by the final image on the eye}}{\color{red}{\text{Angle}} \text{ subtended by the object on the unaided eye}}$$

Why is the magnifying power for these devices defined in terms of the ratio of angles and not in terms of the ratio of sizes of objects and images? Is that because, angle subtended by the object or image is easier to measure when compared to their respective sizes? Or, is that just a convention without any reasons? What happens when we define the magnification in terms of sizes of objects or images? I'm unable to figure out why it shouldn't be done the other way.

Comment: Related [What is the need for angular magnification](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314860/what-is-the-need-for-angular-magnification) and [Magnification vs Magnifying Power](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241095/magnification-vs-magnifying-power/241136#241136)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular size is used because the linear dimension of an object seen in the eyepiece cannot be given. The formula you have cited does give the relationship between magnification power and the angles, final and unaided, subtended on the eye. For example the Moon's angular size is about 0.52 degrees as viewed from Earth. So 10x binoculars would make the Moon appear subtended to an angle of 5.2 degrees. So using this formula we get 10x magnification = 5.2 degrees final / .52 degrees unaided. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With respect to the statement "_...linear dimension of an object seen in the eyepiece cannot be given._", then how do we determine the angular size of the final image formed?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnification#Telescope